# WinAPI Is Region meaningless?

Tags: winapi, gdi, wm-paint

Could you explain me why WinAPI needs InvalidateRgn with its handle to the region to be added to the update region (hRgn) if we have only RECT during BeginPaint while processing WM_PAINT?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*we have only RECT*" You can [`GetUpdateRgn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getupdatergn) inside `WM_PAINT`, just do it before `BeginPaint`.

Answer (score 1):

Win32 API is about 30 years old; there's lots of code in there for backwards compatibility.  There's a perfectly sane `InvalidateRect`.

Having said that, calling `InvalidateRgn` with `bErase=TRUE` will erase a non-rectangular area.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It's alway the question of backwards compatibility. Of course. But who stops the Microsoft add something Like BeginPaintEx to deal with region... That is the question...

Comment: I would guess the number of developers Microsoft have working on WinAPI could be counted on the fingers of one hand.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring the specific (complex) update region is an extremely rare use case. The system is optimized for the most common use case, where applications invalidate and track dirty areas of a window using rectangles. That's what you get when calling [BeginPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint).

If you are in the rare situation where you need the update region, you can call [GetUpdateRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getupdatergn) instead. Since `BeginPaint` validates the update region, you would have to call `GetUpdateRegion` before that.

Why does Windows not just go ahead and invent a `BeginPaintEx` API that returns the update region? Because adding an API is unbelievably expensive, and needs to be well justified. Adding a function that doesn't add any value (as in this case) is hard to justify.